# Full Disk Encryption after suspension and hibernation

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, encryption, disk, xubuntu

I fully encrypted my disk during the installation of Xubuntu 20.04. I need that at each suspension and hibernation it is encrypted back. Is there any solution?
Right now the disk is encrypted only at shutdown.

Comment: The disk is always encrypted. RAM isn't. Is your actual question: "I want it to ask again the passphrase?" because that's not what you're asking (I'm not saying it's possible, I'm saying the question is unclear)

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you mean by "each suspension" the decryption key must be added to RAM, this can never work for you. Suspension is just a very lower power state that loads a user login screen. For hibernation, I'm not sure but you can just enable hibernation and if when the computer boots you get the LUKS decryption password screen, then the RAM does not have the decryption passphrase and you're all set to go. Otherwise, it's shut down the computer whenever you walk away from it.

Comment: Please provide more detail, including what you have searched/researched, and tried/failed... You're using SWAP space in order to hibernate--but that is usually encrypted with a **random key/password at each boot**. Did you set it up to use a manually entered passphrase instead of a random key? If not, unless you can guess what the **random key** is, you cannot do it. You will need to convert to using a manually entered passphrase even for SWAP space.